# What does this definition of contiguous subsequences mean?

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

I don't understand the following definition of a contiguous subsequence:

> A contiguous subsequence of a list S is a subsequence made up of consecutive elements of S.
>
> If S is `{5, 15, -30, 10, -5, 40, 10}`
> then `15, -30, 10` is a contiguous subsequence.

What makes `15, -30, 10` a contiguous subsequence?

Comment: Up-voting to counteract downvote that had no explanation.

Comment: If its from Dasgupta's book, Look at the line "Output: " and read the definition of "maximum sum" a "subsequence of length 0 and has sum 0"

Answer (score 15):

Lets say you have some elements in a subsequence,

then it will be called contiguous iff the elements taken in order are consecutive in original set.

E.g,

**Sequence**=**2,3,abc,5.6,4,abhishek**;

**Subsequence**=**5.6,2,abhishek**;

**Contiguous Subsequence**=**3,abc,5.6 or 5.6,4,abhishek or abc,5.6**.

**Remember, The sequence itself is always a contiguous subsequence.**

Hope it makes the concept clear!

Comment: the note about the whole sequence being a subsequence is a valuable addition

Comment: shouldn't the subsequence be <2, 5.6, abhishek> instead of <5.6, 2, abhishek>?

Answer (score 9):

The form a subset that are next to each other within the set.

```
con·tig·u·ous/kənˈtigyo͞oəs/Adjective
1. Sharing a common border; touching.
2. Next or together in sequence.
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not directly programming related but `15, 30, -15` is a contiguous subsequence because you can find them in the same order inside the given list (without any holes between the elements of course).

Answer (score 4):

In the series (5,15,-30,10,-5,40,10) 5,15,-30 are one after another so they are contiguous but 5,15,40 are not contiguous because we skipped -30,10, and -5 and took 40. In Dasgupta's book, we need to find a sub series of the main series which makes the largest possible sum. Which in this case is 10,-5,40,10. Which is  (10-5+40+10=55).

Answer (score 2):

Uhm, maybe because they are consecutive as per your definition?

Comment: @Brad, respect everybody here please!

Comment: He's asking for an explanation of the definition -- the definition gives that as an example of a contiguous subsequence and he doesn't understand why it's the case

Answer (score 2):

They are elements of your original array and they are all continous.

Answer (score 2):

[Contiguous elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contiguity#Computer_science) are consecutive elements.

Answer (score 1):

Respectively list some elements from array S without skipping any element from the middle of that list.

Answer (score 0):

**Sequences** are just ordered elements.
**S = a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub> ..., a<sub>n</sub>**
for example, a sequence S could be: S = {5, 15, -30, 10, -5, 40, 10}
this can also be written as: S = 5, 15, -30, 10, -5, 40, 10

A **subsequence** of a sequence is where we pick some elements by preserving their relative order, and gaps are allowed in them.
Creating a subsequence is easy. Consider S = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
now delete some elements, without changing the order of the remaining elements (see example).

for example: if S = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
(we delete 2, 4)
then S' = 1, 3, 5 is a subsequence of S
and S'' = 1, 5, 3 is **not a subsequence** of S because the order of 5 and 3 is not preserved

**Contiguous subsequences** are *subsequences* that do not have gaps in them. they are somewhat equivalent to subarrays.
Formally, S' is a subsequence of S if S' = **a<sub>i</sub>, a<sub>i+1</sub>, a<sub>i+2</sub> ..., a<sub>j-1</sub>, a<sub>j</sub>** where 1 <= i <= j <= n, and i and j are both positive integers.

For example: if S = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
then S' = 4, 5, 6 is a contiguous subsequence.
and S'' = 2, 4, 5, 6 although is a subsequence of S, but is **not a contiguous subsequence** of S.

(Do not confuse subsequences with sets. This could be because we sometimes use set notations for them (like {}). Sequences have ordered elements. Just some addition to information is that all contiguous subsequences are still subsequences, but not all subsequences are contiguous subsequences.)

Now, the answer to OPs question becomes obvious.
**15, -30, 10** is a contiguous subsequence because it is both a subsequence (the subsequence maintains the original relative order of elements) and its elements are contiguous (Here, a<sub>2</sub> = 15, a<sub>3</sub> = -30, and a<sub>4</sub> = 10. The indices/positions are continuous natural numbers). Thus it is a contiguous subsequence.

Answer (score -1):

A subsequence can be formed from any subset of items from the original subsequence,
so from above {5,10,40} is a valid subsequence. A contiguous subsequence is more restricted, it requires the elements to be consecutive elements from the list, *NOT* that the values are consecutive but that the positions of the elements taken from the original are consecutive. I  suspect that this distinction was the OPs point of confusion.

Answer (score -2):

`15, -30, 10` is not a contiguous sequence.

The answer from [user brad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988575/what-does-this-definition-of-contiguous-subsequences-mean/3988624#answer-3988624) would indicate that the sequence of numbers you referenced is not contiguous. You can also validate this by running code from [geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/length-largest-subarray-contiguous-elements-set-1/).

Comment: It is contiguous for the sequence provided